# Determining Address type or phone number type with Google Contact API

Tags: php, json, google-contacts-api

I am getting all contacts for a user using Google API

```
 $req = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=10000")
```

From all the responses the Array for phone number and address is like this

```
 Array ( [0] => 12345 [1] => 33453 [2] => 4444 [3] => 123 [4] => 3444 [5] => 444 [6] => 3242 [7] => 2342 ) [gdpostalAddress] => Array ( [0] => ABC 3 kjh, kjh, k jhk j [1] => DEF 3 kjh, kjh, k jhk j ) )
```

So I am getting Index numbers instead of something like `OFFICE, HOME` etc
Any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible in Current Google API..You can check the documentation for further reference as well

Answer (score 0):

The result of contacts feed contains a list of contact objects described here: https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements?hl=hu&csw=1#gdContactKind

gd:phoneNumber@Rel points to an url (namespace like url), that determines the type of phonenumber
etc:
http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home
or 
http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#fax